# Pedir dato en php

Tags: php

Estimados buenos días.

Cómo puedo pedir un dato en php (luego de dar click en el botón submit?).

Tengo el siguiente formulaio inicial donde pido "Código de Producto", "Cantidad" y el botón submit.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$retVal = '
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
            background: #004B85;
            }
        </style>
        <form action="resultados.php" method="get">
            <center>
            <table border="3" bgcolor=white>
                <tr>
                    <td align= "right">
                        Código:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" name="selCodigo" required="required"/>
                    </td>

                    <td align= "right">
                        Cantidad:
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" name="cantidad" required="required"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit" value="Calcular">
            </center>
        </form>
    </head>
</html>';
echo $retVal;
?>
```

Al dar click en el botón submint ejecuta los cálculos pero solo unos poquitos productos tienen varios porcentajes de liberación.

El código del archivo resultados.php que necesito completar es más o menos así:

```
<?php
$selCodigo = $_GET(selCodigo);
$libera = mysql_query('SELECT porcentaje FROM liberaciones WHERE codigo = "'.$selCodigo.'" ;');
$numDatos = mysql_num_rows($libera);
switch (TRUE){
    case ($numDatos > 1):
        // (Esta es la parte que no se cómo haerlo)
        // El producto tiene "Varios" porcentajes de liberaciones
        // y debe desplegar (por ejemplo una ventana modal)
        // con los porcentajes de liberación para que el
        // usuario escoja.
        //
        // El 0.10 por ciento de los productos tienen este problema
        $porcenLibAdv = "El porcentaje que escoje el usuario";
    case ($numDatos == 1):
        // El producto solo tiene un único porcentaje liberatorio, aquí no hay problema.
        // El 9.9 por ciento de los productos tienen un valor liberatorio
        $liberaArray = mysql_fetch_array($libera);
        $porcenLibAdv = $liberaArray['porcentaje'];
    default:
        // No hay porcentaje liberatorio, aquí tampoco hay problema.
        // El 90 por ciento de los productos no tienen liberación
        $porcenLibAdv = 0;
}

$resultado = $valor * $porcenLibAdv;

?>
```

Existe forma de pedir ese dato en resultados.php? o necesariamente el usuario lo tiene que ingresar en inicial.php?

Comment: si se agrega debe ser:
$resultado = $valor * 1+($porcenLibAdv/100);
si se resta debe ser:
$resultado = $valor * 1-($porcenLibAdv/100);
en caso de que quiera sacar dicho piorsentaje del valor:
$resultado = $valor * ($porcenLibAdv/100);

Comment: Sé un poco más especifico en tu pregunta para que la comunidad te pueda brindar una respuesta favorable.

Comment: Podrias usar Ajax

Answer (score 0):

Para recoger datos enviados a través de un `<form>`, dependiendo de si usaste GET o POST, tienes que preguntar si el valor que has enviado existe o no, y si existe, lo recoges en una variable.

```
$porcenLibAdv = null;

if (isset($_GET["porcenLibAdv"])) {
    $porcenLibAdv = $_GET["porcenLibAdv"];
}
```

Si usaste POST, lo mismo pero `$_POST["porcenLibAdv"]`

Y ahora que tienes el valor, ya puedes usarlo como quieras en tu código.

Comment: Usa un primer submit para enviar el porcentaje a la página php donde quieras recogerlo, y en esa segunda página haces los cálculos. También puedes enviar el porcentaje a la misma página, pero tendrías que usar "if" para ocultar el calculo cuando estés introduciendo el valor.

Comment: Estimado amigo. Mi objetivo era hacer la verificación de las Liberaciones en "Resultados.php". No es mi objetivo verficar en "Inicial.php" y pasarlo $_ a "Resultados.php". Es posible hacer esa verificación en "Resultados.php"??

Answer (score 0):

PHP proporciona una gran cantidad de variables predefinidas para todos los scripts. Las variables representan de todo, desde variables externas hasta variables de entorno incorporadas, desde los últimos mensajes de error hasta los últimos encabezados recuperados.

- $_GET — Variables HTTP GET
- $_POST — Variables POST de HTTP
- $_FILES — Variables de subida de ficheros HTTP
- $_REQUEST — Variables HTTP Request
- $_SESSION — Variables de sesión

puede visitar el siguiente enlace: [PHP - variables predefinidas](http://php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.php)

Si lo que deseas es insertar los datos directamente en la url te recomiendo Request:
$variablerecibida=$_REQUEST['namevariable'];

Comment: Estimado amigo. Mi objetivo era hacer la verificación de las Liberaciones en "Resultados.php". No es mi objetivo verficar en "Inicial.php" y pasarlo $_ a "Resultados.php". Es posible hacer esa verificación en "Resultados.php".

Comment: claro, amigo si utilizas el REQUEST, lo haces de la siguiente manera en inicial.php, le envias los parametros por ejemplo con `http://localhost/ruta/resultados.php?dato1=sss&dato2=3223` con esto en resultados.php recibes asi `$variable=$_request['dato1']; $variable2=$_request['dato2']; `, entonces tambien puedes enviar datos con POSt, del lado inicial.php creas un formulario `<form method="post" action="http://localhost/ruta/resultados.php"><input id="dato1" type="text"><input id="dato2" type="text"></form>`, y en resultados.php `$variable=$_post['dato1']; $variable2=$_post['dato2']; `.